# css center default value in select dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am using `select` and `ng-options` in angularjs to show a list of years that I construct myself. I pass the current year as the default value to the select.

**here is the [plunker link](https://embed.plnkr.co/N6mhZQqq1Pf137WdSB3s/).**

### My question is:

How to center the list on the default value?
My plunker is not complete because my real situation is like the one found here
http://www.cliptheme.com/demo/clip-two/AngularJs-Admin/STANDARD/#/app/form/wizard

Go to **Forms** / **Form Wizard** / **Step 3 Billings**

as you can see, by choosing a year, and then clicking back again on it, the menu is centered on that selected year.

But my problem is that when I pass the default year value to it, as if I have already selected, and then I click back on the list, I should see it centered on that default value, but it isn't. Once I click again on that year, and click on the list again, I see it centered.

In other words, passing a year as default value doesn't play the same role as if I selected it for the first time by clicking, because when I re-click again, it is not centered. How can we fix this problem?

**Here is the CSS file for the selecter I am using: [css link](http://www.cliptheme.com/demo/clip-two/AngularJs-Admin/STANDARD/assets/css/styles.css)**, this is not included in the plunker nor in the snippet, because I couldn't properly reproduce that CSS on the plunker, if you can, please do it.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.dates = {};
    $scope.years = [{value: 'Year', disabled: true}];
    var current_year = new Date().getFullYear();
    for(var i = current_year - 20; i <= current_year + 20; i++){
        $scope.years.push({value: i + ''});
    }
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getFullYear();

    $scope.dates.startYear = n;

});
```

```html
   <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

        <label class="control-label">Year</label>
  <select name="startYear" ng-model="dates.startYear" id="startYear"
          ng-options="year.value as year.value disable when year.disabled for year in years"
          required>
      <option value="" disabled >Choose one</option>
  </select>
</div>
</body>
```

### update 1:

Here is the directive that handles this particular element:

https://pastebin.com/0diFfH6t

### update 2:

**Here is the plunker that shows exactly the problem even after Dekel's solution.
https://plnkr.co/edit/aWbZkp4xitvBcMmhHadI?p=preview**

***as you can see, on the page load, when clicked on the dropdown menu, it doesn't center on the default value.***

Comment: the dropdown.. is some angular custom directive provide from the template??? i try trproduce including the css but. when i look the code from the template it adds some ul and span.. soy maybe its a directive provider for the themplate.

Comment: @JesusCarrasco please see the question, i added the directive.

Comment: sorry pastebin arent working on my network. :(

Comment: @JesusCarrasco here is the updated plunker with css and directive altogether https://plnkr.co/edit/9LRzK6lBIUgIKdTQCeRI?p=preview

Comment: here it is as it appears on the site http://www.cliptheme.com/demo/clip-two/AngularJs-Admin/STANDARD/assets/js/directives/select.js

Comment: you want every time the drop its open alawys scroll to the year selected ??

Comment: @JesusCarrasco yes, it should scroll to the default value passed to it, using `$scope.dates.startYear` or when the user clicks and chooses one year and then clicks back again it should scroll to the year.

Comment: @Bonnard you changed the question and now you are not using a regular select, now this is a complete different question...

Comment: @Dekel i haven't changed my original question, I have already mentioned that i am using the directive and the custom css, it is already in the original question, i just integrated them to my plunker that is it. i have give the original website where i took the idea. everything was there from beginning. I would appreciate if you could adapt your solution to these specifications.

Comment: @Bonnard after some debugging, the focus event doesnt get called with the custom directive. if you console.log it, those events never get fired only changed does.

Comment: @Deckerz yes that is right, but how to fix this? what is the solution to center the value on dropdown?

Comment: @Bonnard also on http://www.cliptheme.com/demo/clip-two/AngularJs-Admin/STANDARD/#/app/form/wizard the dropdown doesnt center on the selected input for me either.

Answer (score 3):

> First I gotta say that the `<select>` tag is not a standard tag, since the rendering of that tag is partially done by the OS and not the browser, so it behaves a little different then other elements, and you can't really apply css to everything you need there.

Having said that - there are (almost) always hacks that can be done, and I'm going to show this example as one of the hacks:

```js
function selectfocus() {
    el = event.target;
    sizeWhenOpen = 5;
    el.size=sizeWhenOpen;
    totalHeight = el.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    heightPerOption = el.scrollHeight/el.options.length;
    currentIndex = el.selectedIndex;
    el.scrollTop = heightPerOption * (currentIndex - Math.floor(sizeWhenOpen/2));
}
```

```html
<select 
  onfocus="selectfocus()"
  onblur="this.size=1;"
  onchange="this.size=1; this.blur();">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>13</option>
    <option>14</option>
    <option>15</option>
    <option>16</option>
    <option>17</option>
    <option>18</option>
    <option>19</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>21</option>
</select>
```

Since we can't control the number of elements that will be displayed when the `<select>` is open, i used two states - one when closed (size=0) and one when open (size=5 in the example). When the select is open - I took the current selected option (based on the index) and scrolled the select to the relevant position do make sure it's centered.

> Another important note - inside your application you might need use css to position (absolute/relative) the select/it's container in order to keep the original size (the size when open is bigger than the size when closed).

And here is the angular version, based on your plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/eV1sPxENpcO1xXcS6JL3?p=preview

> Final note - If you need exact things from the `<select>` tag in your website - use an implementation of drop-down that is based on regular html elements and not select :)

Comment: ok nice! it is working your plunker. But i can't reproduce it on my dev env. Did you take into account the css file that I shared? and also the directive? something is interfering inbetween. don't know what.

Comment: As mentioned - you might need to do some change with the css to make it work exactly the same. There will need to be a wrapper around the select with position relative, and set the select itself with position absolute inside that wrapper

Comment: thanks, but i am very lost to implement exactly what you said. could you give some clear explanations? thanks

Comment: i added the wrappers as said, but can't make it work with the css to which i have shared the link, and also the directive.

Comment: Here is an example with the css you provided: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ti9edukdtedTucPFJZMO?p=preview

Comment: please see the updated answer with https://plnkr.co/edit/aWbZkp4xitvBcMmhHadI?p=preview that shows exactly the problem even with your solution included.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just write some CSS to target the span tag?

```
span { text-align: center; }
```

or better yet.... tag it to an id or class

```
.className { text-align: center; }
#idName { text-align: center; }
```

Below is a functional plunker.

[Plunker Example](https://embed.plnkr.co/LRBm0bFgu3Q3Nf5v5eoN/)

Comment: can you suggest a plunker with your solution based on this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/aWbZkp4xitvBcMmhHadI?p=preview  
?

Comment: Seeing that they are actually in spans... here is the plunker that I made just referencing the span instead of the option element! https://embed.plnkr.co/LRBm0bFgu3Q3Nf5v5eoN/

Comment: but it is not working as it supposed to. it should center the default value.

Comment: LOL! i don't mean center the text '2017' horizontally! I mean, when you click on the dropdown list, the list should be centered on that value! rather than scrolling down to look for that. If you click on any other value, and select, let's say 2020, and then click back again on the dropdown list, you will see the list is centered on 2020. But this behaviour doesn't happen when the list is clicked for THE FIRST TIME with the default value.

Comment: refer to Dekel's answer, he has done a great job! but it is not working with my select directive and custom css.

Comment: seems to me like your class that you add 'class="cs-select cs-skin-slide"' is causing the issue

Comment: it is not causing the issue, I want to use that css! and i want it to be centered on the default value on opening the dropdown. if i didn't have this css class, then Dekel's answer was already acceptable!

Answer (score 2):

With reference to your Update 2 plunk link you just need to update your CSS. Specify the width(whatever you want) of your area in which you have to place the select box. This will surely fix your problem :)

```
.myctrl {
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that your example on cliptheme.com does not scroll at all. It just stays centered because the div keeps it scroll position.

So to solve your issue you just need to calculate the right position and set it to the `.cs-options` div. One event which could be used is `_toggleSelect`.

Working example (see line 370-372):

https://plnkr.co/edit/XgoeU8igSSeu044EFBCV

This is just a hint and your final solution should be more sophisticated (like not query the elements every time the list is opened).

Answer (score 0):

You can apply styling to id of select box as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
#startYear{
  padding:0 1% 0 10%;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">


      <label class="control-label">Year</label>
      <select name="startYear" ng-model="dates.startYear" id="startYear"
              ng-options="year.value as year.value disable when year.disabled for year in years"
              required>
          <option value="" disabled >Choose one</option>
      </select>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i tried it, but it is not working as expected, can you provide a plunker with working solution?

Comment: Can you please let me what is the issue you are facing with above sample please.

Comment: please see the question it is updated and i added the directive.

Comment: Now i got your question, Apology for last time. Seems drop down is not getting initialed in the code.  Please initialise the dropdown before clicking on it like this $('selector').dropdown() , I guess its bootstrap control so it should work.

Comment: can you suggest where and how it should be? i am lost here.

Comment: could you please help with your solution? i need it please